# Can a Buck converter operated at 200kHz be used to step down 230V DC input to 5V DC output?

Tags: switches, buck, converter

I was wondering whether this type of converter is possible. Any clarification on it will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what makes you doubt it?

Comment: Some LED lightbulbs use a buck converter to convert mains voltage into a low DC voltage. These might not operate at 200 kHz but one could be designed for that.

Comment: Could such a thing be designed?  Probably.  But if you are posting this question, you are a long way from designing a mains power supply, which makes specifying implementation details like "200 KHz" highly dubious.  Why do you want it to operate at that frequency?  What you should do is go study the *appropriate* solutions for your *application* need, either as a module you can buy or at most as a well proven design topology considered appropriate for your usage.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for this site and will likely be closed (too open-ended and somewhat opinion-based as the requirements are far too vague).

Comment: Maybe. But it would be quite hard. 200 kHz means 5 microseconds rate, and 5/230 means about 2% duty cycle. That's in the order of 100ns. Some high voltage (20V and above) input regulators can't output 1V due to Ton minimum limit.

Comment: 1)  How many amps must the supply output.  2)  Are there any size or weight or cost constraints on the design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not the best option.

In a buck converter, you have either two FETs (synchronous) or one FET and one diode (not synchronous). Both components must withstand the full input voltage plus some margin, and also the full output current. So if you want 5V 1A at the output, you'll need FETs and/or diodes that can switch quickly enough and withstand say, 300V and 1A with good efficiency.

On the other hand, in a converter based on a transformer, the primary side transistor(s) only have to handle the primary current. For a 5V 1A output, you'd have about 20-25 mA primary current at 230V DC.

Switching losses are proportional to the product of current, voltage, and switching time. Therefore when there is a large input/output voltage ratio, using a transformer minimizes switching losses by running much lower current through the switching device. It also allows to use lower current devices which are cheaper and require less drive current, further reducing losses. Gate drive losses are important especially if the driver is powered from high voltage through a linear regulator, which dramatically multiplies losses.

Then there's ON-time. With a ratio of 5/230, duty cycle will be 2.1%, at 200kHz that's an ON-time of about 100ns. Low enough to be impractical. It will spend almost as much time switching as it will spend being on, which means switching losses will really be a problem.

And you need a high side driver for that FET, which means more complication.

A transformer will operate with a much more comfortable duty cycle, and the switching device is low-side, easy to drive.

The inductor also plays an important part. In a buck converter, it carries the full output current. Also if you want a reasonable inductor current ripple, say... for 5V 1A let's go with 500mA ripple... and you decide on a more realistic ON-time like 300ns, lowering the frequency, then you'll need a somewhat large inductor that will take the full current.

That's why transformers usually work better for high input/output ratio power conversion, even if you don't need the isolation.

Note the same applies to boost converters.

Answer (score 1):

200 kHz is a rather high frequency.  The mosfet gate driver in the buck switch needs to supply a current proportional to frequency.  Some commercially available converter ICs run at 40 kHz internally for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a Buck converter operated at 200kHz be used to step down 230V DC
> input to 5V DC output?

In theory, yet it could.  Whether or not you would want to depends on the details of your design.

You are going to have a hard time finding any regular buck converter ICs that run at 230VDC.  In fact the highest-voltage one I know of are made by Analog Devices and only go up to 150V DC max input.

**OPTION1:**
What you could look for is off-line converter ICs.  There are plenty of them that can operate at hundreds of volts.  Typically they are operated at a few 10s of kHz, but some can go to higher frequencies up to the low MHz range.

Some examples would be...

Monolithic Power Systems, HF900GS-Z, up to 900V, and up to 300kHz
https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/HF900/document_id/86

On Semi, NCP1399, operates up to 600V, and up to 750KHz.
https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1399-D.PDF

ST Micro, VIPER35HE, operates up to 800V, and up to 225KHz.
https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c6/9e/aa/3b/99/fa/4d/fa/DM00135237.pdf/files/DM00135237.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00135237.pdf

**OPTION2:**
You didn't specify where you were getting the 230V DC, and you also didn't specify how many watts the supply needs to provide, or any size or weight constraints.  If the power is actually coming from an AC source (like from your wall) then you could try running the power through a 10:1 step-down transformer before rectifying to DC.  In that case you are only dealing with a few 10s of volts (not 230V).  That makes the problem a lot easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

is it possible? sure, can it be done? yes but you need some fast switches (think GaN)

Fundamentally you need a duty cycle of \$\frac{5}{230} = 2.17% \$  NOTE this is assuming you really have 230Vdc and not rectified 230Vac. If you are rectifying single phase 230Vac then the duty cycle would be \$\frac{5}{230\times \sqrt{2}} = 1.53% \$

the required on-time with a PWM switching frequency of 200kHz is therefore 76.85ns.
You want to ensure that the devices are switching with a higher switching rise/fall time to ensure a square pulse is applied. Lets say the switching time needs to be 10x this. Thus you need devices with a ton and toff ~ 7ns

Take for instance: GPI65008DF56  ( https://o4s.4c7.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/GPI65008DF56_V2.0.pdf). This has 8ns rise and fall time.

You then need a driver of suitably low propagation delay and output drive strength to realise this need:  take for instance: UCC27611 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27611.pdf

Now the controller? you will need a controller that can operate with at least 4-10 times the bandwidth of the PWM to ensure the phase margin of the buck can maintain stability. OR... you run at a fixed duty and rely on a well regulated 230Vdc and generate say 6V and post-reg with an LDO to manage tolerances